# Fast numerical methods for surface integration of discrete points

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I have some RGBD data and I want to be able to integrate a segmented surface to get the total reflectivity of the surface (take it for granted that the surface can be segmented from other objects and surfaces). For those unfamiliar with RGBD, e.g. from something like flash lidar or stereo depth cameras, you basically get two images that give, firstly, the RGB intensity of the scene and, secondly, the depth estimates of the scene. In other words, you have a 3D point cloud with RGB intensity. The surface intensities are all single valued along depth which leads to simpler surface integral, but the surface intensities are also only discrete samples

$$S = \int\int h(x,y,f(x,y))\sqrt{f_x^2 + f_y^2 + 1}$$

where $f_x$ and $f_y$ are the partial derivatives of the surface. So, I think a decent approximation comes from discretizing $f(x,y)$ and $h(x,y,z)$

$$h(x,y) = \sum_i \sum_j \Pi(\frac{x-x_i}{\Delta x})\Pi(\frac{y-y_i}{\Delta y})$$
$$f(x,y) = \sum_\alpha \sum_\gamma\Pi(\frac{x-x_\alpha}{\Delta x})\Pi(\frac{y-y_\gamma}{\Delta y})$$

with $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ the pixel sizes, where $\Pi$ is Heaviside Pi, and the $x_i$ are determined by pixel pitch. Which really just points to using the intensity pixels as mini-integration regions and summing them all up with the weighting of the depth differential. For the differentials in the surface integral, I suppose a simple central difference formula should work. So that's the approach I'd take, but is there something more clever that I'm missing that would make the discrete integration either faster or more accurate? Maybe there's a nice, established technique out there (my search mostly turned up people trying to estimate meshes)?

Comment: The immediate concern is the discontinuity of the Heaviside function which may compromise our ability to estimate the error. Is there a specific selection of the points $(x_i,y_i)$ which is relevant, such as a uniform grid?

Comment: @Carl Thanks for the reply. Yes, the images come from detectors with pixel separation corresponding a uniform grid. Essentially, they give uniform samples of intensity $h$ and surface "depth" $f$.

Comment: I did not see it until now and I am not sure it matters much, but is $h$ a function of $2$ or $3$ variables? You have both options present in the current text.